# Cannot get json from remote api AND load images from web reliably

Tags: ios, swift

I have an ios12 APP that loads a list of images from a remote api (returns some simple JSON) and then displays these in imageviews contained in a TableViewController. All works well the first time i go into that screen but subsequent views are missing the images.

I am using the func viewWillAppear function to load the data to ensure this happens every time the screen is viewed and i'm using a dispatch group to encapsulate the downloading of the JSON with the dispatchgroup.notify to trigger the table to reload it's data but all to no avail.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getImagesFromAPI()
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func getImagesFromAPI() {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    if let url = URL(string: baseImageURL + "?eventId=" + 
String(globalEventId)) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data,response,error in
            if let data = data {
                if let tmp = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8), 
tmp.count > 3 {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do {
                        self.images = try 
decoder.decode([EventImage].self, from: tmp.data(using: .utf8)!)
                    }
                    catch  {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }}.resume()
    }
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("setting up cell \(indexPath.row)")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", 
for: indexPath) as! PhotoTableViewcell

    let url = URL(string: baseImageURL + String(eventId) + "/" + 
images[indexPath.row].eventImageFilename)

    cell.eventImage.sd_setImage(with: url)

    return cell
}
```

I'm using the SDWebImage to get the remote images but the problem seems to be with the JSON not loading so the EventImages array is empty?

Comment: Probably unrelated but you are misusing `DispatchGroup`. Delete everything which belongs to `DispatchGroup` and reload the table view on the **main thread** right after the `decoder.decode` line. Are the concatenated URLs valid? I'd recommend to use the (more reliable) API of `URL` to build paths (for example `let url = baseImageURL .appendingPathComponent(String(eventId)).appendingPathComponent(images[indexPath.row].eventImageFilename)`)

Comment: The DispatchGroup variable is created at the class level


class EventPhotosTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var eventId = 0
    var baseImageURL = "https://www.awenmedia.co.uk/clients/eventOne/endPoints/eventImages/"
    var dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    var images = [EventImage]()

The URLs are working correctly as i do see the images on first entry to this screen.  I will try removing the DispatchGroup code as suggested and change where i reload the table data. Thx...

Comment: Reloading the tableview right after the decoder.decode line produces an issue that this is not on the main thread?

Comment: Please read my comment carefully: I wrote *and reload the table view on the **main thread***

Comment: Apologies - i have changed the code to the code below and all works well now. Thank you for your help.
do {
                            self.images = try decoder.decode([EventImage].self, from: tmp.data(using: .utf8)!)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async (execute: {
                                 self.tableView.reloadData()
                            })
                        }
                        catch  {
                            print(error)
                        }